# WebSocket Response Function Execution

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, websocket, execution

I have a code however the problem with it is that `function getip()` doesn't execute first. I haven't coded in Javascript much so I don't really know what's going on. I want the `console.log('connected!')` to execute after the `function getip()` has fully completed.

I would appreciate if someone would make the changes required for this to happen with some brief explanation if possible.

```
(async function getip() {
    var responses = [];
    var ips = [ "IP1", "IP2" ]
    var length = ips.length
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        (async function() {
            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + ips[i] + ':80');
            await new Promise(function(res) {
                var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                console.log("Socket connection timeout", ws.readyState);
                                console.log(ws.url);
                                if (ws.readyState == 3){
                                    responses.push('connected')
                                } else {
                                    responses.push('not connected')
                                }
                                ws.close();
                },5000);
            });
        })();
    }
})();

console.log('connected!')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things happening:

The `getip` function is asynchronous, meaning it will not block other code from running while it is executing. This causes the `console.log('connected')` to be called because of the asynchronous nature.

Your `Promise` doesn't call `res` anywhere. That means that the promise will never resolve and therefor, your `await` will never stop waiting.

In the `setTimeout` in your promise you're looking for the `readyState` on the web socket instance. Currently what you're checking is if that state is `3`, which means closed, which it will (probably) not be, because you just opened the web socket. Instead, close the connection and *reject* the promise, saying that the promise has failed.

Use the `onopen` and `onerror` events to monitor if the web sockets has successfully opened or when an error occurs. In the `onopen` function call `resolve` to successfully close the promise. In the `onerror` callback `reject` the promise and pass some data to it so you can read the error log. In both cases, clear the timeout.

Instead of `await`-ing each `Promise`, collect all of them in a single array and use either [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await the array of promises. This will ensure that all web sockets are opened in parallel. When everything goes right, the `console.log('connected')` will log to the console. Otherwise, if an error was produced by one of the promises, it will log an error.

This topic is quite difficult to grasp and will need some practice to get that *click* moment.

The example below uses all practices described above. Examine it and feel free to ask any follow-up questions if you have them.

```
async function getip() {
  const ips =  ["IP1", "IP2"];
  const responses = ips.map(ip => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${ip}:80`);
    
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Save the state before closing, otherwise it will always be the closed state.
      const currentState = ws.readyState;
      ws.close();
      reject({
        message: 'Socket connection timeout', 
        state: currentState
      });
    }, 5000);

    ws.onopen = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      resolve(ws);
    };

    ws.onerror = event => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      reject({
        message: 'Socket connection error',
        event
      });
    };
  }));

  const sockets = await Promise.all(responses);
  return sockets;
}
```

```
getip().then(sockets => {
  console.log('connected!', sockets);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment:  there are a lot of problems in my code lmao, but how do you get the function to run synchronously? I've tried removing the async but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you would want that? Because this is exactly a scenario where `async` is the way to go. Removing `async` makes the `getit()` function synchronous, but the code running inside of it is still using promises, which are inheritely  asynchronous. Making a connection, like you do with the sockets, can take (relatively speaking) a while. Therefor allowing other code to run while waiting is a good strategy. I've edited the answer and removed the IIFE to show you should use this function. Feel free to ask more questions. :)

Comment: I am trying to make a console interface on the web that would be connected to a bunch of virtual machines on my computer. So I need to make sure that it connects before any it shows up the console and the commands don't work ;)

Comment: Well, there you have it. You connect to your virtual machines, wait for the connection to be established, and *then* you show the console. The async part is making sure that all other code on the same thread is not blocked until that *then* moment happens. And it gives you control what to do when the loading is finished.

Comment: I tried making another promise the only problem is that now nothing is being executed after the function.

Comment: What do mean *making another promise*? Could you include a JSFiddle of some sorts to show what you're trying?

Comment: Nevermind, it does work in a way, I hope it did work with the whole connection process completing first but this is good enough. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I'm confused, it's precisely what my example does. It connects all web sockets, waits for **all** of them to be *opened* and then it proceeds. And no problem, happy to help.

Comment: Yes but can all of them be opened at the same time, like multi threading or something... I'll share a layout of what I'm trying to make.. I haven't started with anything yet but this will clear things out a lot.

Comment: https://ibb.co/tPMBKHD Here is a rough layout. There is a bunch of virtual machines and terminals that are connected. Is there a way to make them all connection at the same time and then continue with everything else instead of waiting for a socket to connect one by one. I think this explains better. :)

Comment: [Let's continue in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229224/discussion-between-anonymous-user-and-emiel-zuurbier)